# Firestore emulator "CREATE" operation becomes "UPDATE" operation when turning wifi off then on

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Flutter app and I am using Firestore emulator locally on my machine.  I am running the app on a real Android device with no sim card.  There is only wifi available to the device.

I have a button in the app that is supposed to CREATE two records in Firestore using batch.  Something like this:

```
    final batch = _firestore.batch()
      ..set(_firestore.doc(docRef1, {
         ...
         ...
      })
      ..set(docRef2), {
        ...
        ...
      });

    try {
      await batch.commit();
    } catch (e, st) {
      debugPrint('show error');
      debugPrint('show stack trace');
    }
```

When there is wifi and I click the button, both records are created and things go smooth.  The CREATE Firestore security rule passes with no problem.

However, if I follow these steps, I get an error:

- turn the wifi off
- click the button
- wait for couple seconds
- turn wifi on again

The error says that the update operation failed.  However, I don't have an UPDATE.  I have a CREATE.  here is a sample of what the error is saying.  It is trying to use the update security rule even though I am %100 sure these two docs do not exist in Firestore.

```
W/Firestore( 6158): (24.4.0) [Firestore]: Write failed at docRef1: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=
W/Firestore( 6158): false for 'update' @ L382, cause=null}
```

Anyone knows anything about this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you encounter that issue because the Firestore's offline data support uses local cache and syncs it with the server when the device is online.
I think to solve that issue is to `clearData` the `firesore`

Use this code:

```
firestore.clearData();
```

Comment: Where and when should I clear the data?